# Why I get PermissionError if file is closed? (Python)

Tags: python, function, csv, file, class

I get this error while I'm running my code:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: error
```

but my file is closed, can you please help?

```
    def delete_employee(self, new_employee):
    employees_csv_data = self.open_and_read_file(self.list_of_employees)
    with open(EMPLOYEES_EDIT_FILE, 'w') as updated_csv:
        writer = csv.writer(updated_csv)
        if str(new_employee.employee_id) not in str(employees_csv_data.values):
            print(EMPLOYEE_DOESNT_EXIST_IN_FILE_MSG)
        else:
            for row in employees_csv_data.values:
                if new_employee.employee_id != str(row[0]):
                    writer.writerow(row)

    os.rename(EMPLOYEES_EDIT_FILE, self.list_of_employees)
    os.remove(self.list_of_employees)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some other application is accessing this file. Try to delete it and create it again or restart the system.